# UI event issues with reaction game

Tags: unity, c#

I'm making my first real video game. You have to click either on the left or right side on time or else you lose (note: the code I'm about to post doesn't have the timing, don't worry about that, I haven't added it yet). My question is why when the player clicks a UI button that's on the left or right side based on where they're instructed to click, nothing... happens. This is the main script, and all of it is relevant because the whole game isn't done yet, and this small amount is just what I've created so far.

I have done my research. I have been looking up everything I can think of for the past day now.

```csharp
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.Advertisements; // coming soon

public class Game: MonoBehaviour {

  public Button playBtn;

  public Button clickSideLBtn;
  public Button clickSideRBtn;

  public Text clickSideLTxt;
  public Text clickSideRTxt;

  public Image playIcon;
  public Image pauseIcon;

  private float correctSide = 0;

  private GameManager gameManager;

  private bool hasAnswered = true;

  private AudioSource audioData;

  private void setSideActive(float side, bool state) {
    if (state) {
      correctSide = side;
    } else {
      if (side == 0) {
        correctSide = 1;
      } else {
        correctSide = 0;
      }
    }

    if (side == 0) {
      clickSideLTxt.gameObject.SetActive(state);
      clickSideLBtn.gameObject.SetActive(state);
    } else {
      clickSideRTxt.gameObject.SetActive(state);
      clickSideRBtn.gameObject.SetActive(state);
    }
  }

  void Start() {
    audioData = GetComponent<AudioSource>();

    gameManager = GetComponent<GameManager>();

    pauseIcon.gameObject.SetActive(false);

    gameManager.gameIsStarted = false;

    setSideActive(0, false);
    setSideActive(1, false);

    StartCoroutine(HandleUpdate());
  }

  private IEnumerator HandleUpdate() {
    for (;;) {
      DoUpdate();

      yield return new WaitForSeconds(2.0f);
    }
  }

  void DoUpdate() {
    if (gameManager.gameIsStarted && hasAnswered) {
      hasAnswered = false;

      if (Random.value > 0.5f) {
        setSideActive(0, true);
        setSideActive(1, false);
        audioData.Play(0);
      } else {
        setSideActive(1, true);
        setSideActive(0, false);
        audioData.Play(0);
      }
    }
  }
  void OnEnable() {
    //Register Button Events
    playBtn.onClick.AddListener(() => playBtnCallback());
    clickSideRBtn.onClick.AddListener(() => clickSideR());
    clickSideLBtn.onClick.AddListener(() => clickSideL());

  }

  private void playBtnCallback() {
    if (gameManager.gameIsStarted) {
      gameManager.EndGame();
    } else if (!(gameManager.gameIsStarted)) {
      gameManager.gameIsStarted = true;
      playIcon.gameObject.SetActive(false);
      pauseIcon.gameObject.SetActive(true);
    }
  }

  private void clickSideR() {
    if (correctSide == 1) {
      hasAnswered = true;
      setSideActive(1, false);
      // yay, you did it right, don't do anything, other scripts keep the game alive until you tell it not to
    } else {
      gameManager.EndGame();
    }
  }

  private void clickSideL() {
    if (correctSide == 0) {
      hasAnswered = true;
      setSideActive(0, false);
      // yay, you did it right, don't do anything, other scripts keep the game alive until you tell it not to
    } else {
      gameManager.EndGame();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you try to add a breakpoint and step-by-step debug your code?

Comment: I will try that.